# How to conduct simple effect analysis if there is a two-way interaction in linear mixed models

Tags: interaction, linear-model

I am doing Linear mixed models with group (ASD vs TD) and distractor type (face and non-face) as fixed effects and the participant as a random effect.  Each participant's age is considered as the covariate. Dependent variable (DV) is binomial:

```
depvar.lmer = glmer(depvar ~ group * dist_type +C_age+ (1|pp), 
  datafile, family = binomial)
```

After I run this model, I get a two-way interaction effect. Then, I do the simple effect to compare the influence of distractor type on DV for each group, and the codes are shown below:

```
m.1 = glmer(depvar ~ dist_type  + (1|pp),
  subset(datafile, group=='ASD'), family = binomial)
m.2 = glmer(depvar ~ dist_type + (1|pp),
  subset(datafile, group=='TD'), family = binomial)
```

However, when I run it, `m.1` fails to converge. I really want to look at the distractor effects for each group, so I wonder if I can do analyses for both groups separately in the Lmms. Or is there another method available to solve this problem.

I appreciate any suggestions.